# How to get a colonial nation to trigger?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

As the Netherlands, I'm on a quest for world domination. My current enemies are Great Britain, Spain and Portugal, and I would love to take over their colonies. In my last war against GB, I annexed all of British Columbia, thinking it would immediately trigger into forming Dutch Columbia. But it didn't. Instead I was left hanging with 175% overextension. (Although I didn't get any rebels or events. Also, I don't think I should get overextension for overseas provinces. Anyone know what's going on here?) However, once one of my nearby colonies became self-sustaining, this triggered the entire area into forming Dutch Columbia.

So if I want to take over enemy colonial nations, I should just annex them, ignore the overextension, and then settle nearby. Once the colony finishes, the entire region will form a new colonial nation. However, many of the colonial nations I want to conquer don't have free land nearby (or in some cases, I'm unsure as to whether the nearby land falls under the same colonial region). How do I get these colonies to trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone else is having this problem, you just need to core 5 provinces, or the amount of provinces you need to have 5 in that place. You dont need 5 to colonize, you need 5 cores to make a colonial nation. Of course, colonize give you free cores.

Comment: This is certainly the right answer now. Not sure if this was already the case at the time of the question (2 and a half years ago), but that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 6):

I also asked this question on the [Paradox Forums](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/showthread.php?761572-How-to-get-a-colonial-nation-to-trigger), where Heliocon and londoner247 were kind enough to answer.

In the words of londoner247:

> Once you have five cored provinces in a Colonial Region then all the
>   provinces you control in that region will switch to your new Colonial
>   Nation and they will get cores on all of them. So, in your situation,
>   if you can handle the overextension and there are five spare provinces
>   in the Colonial Region (assuming you have no colonies there already)
>   then your best bet is to build five colonies and let it all switch at
>   that stage.
>
> If you conquer territory in a Colonial Region where you already have a
>   Colonial Nation then each province you take will immediately switch
>   but without a core so your Colonial Nation may get overextension
>   issues and you may need to keep an eye on it to help with the rebel
>   stomping.